# Appending to a list in javascript

Tags: javascript

When attempting to append to my list it just keeps adding it to the end of the same list item. Here is my js:

```
var title = document.createElement("h1");
var subTitle = document.createElement("h3");
var img = document.createElement("img");
var list = document.createElement("li");
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("container");
var myList = document.getElementById("pokemon");
var keepGoing = true;
function pokemonList(){
    var theList = prompt("Enter one of your favorite pokemon");
    list.textContent = theList;
    myList.appendChild(list);
    keepGoing = confirm("Would you like to add another pokemon?");
    if(keepGoing)
        pokemonList();
}

<body>
    <div id = "container"></div>
    <ol id="pokemon"></ol>
    <script src="pageGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>myPage();</script>
    <script>pokemonList();</script>
</body>
```

Edit: the first problem was fixed but now the first element is replaced everytime I enter in a new pokemon.

Comment: Please include a minimal **complete** example. The code you've posted is missing several key pieces (such as the creation of a `list` variable) that make it impossible to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createTextNode` just adds text, it doesn't create a new `li`. Try this instead:

```
function pokemonList(){
    var theList = prompt("Enter one of your favorite pokemon");
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.textContent = theList;
    document.getElementById('pokemon').appendChild(node);
    var keepGoing = confirm("Would you like to add another pokemon?");
    if(keepGoing) {
      pokemonList();
    }
}
```

Comment: With this my list is just resetting. Every time I enter something new in it replaces the first list item.

Comment: It's working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/c4fxaqs7/

Comment: Yup I got it working thank you!